# Active Singn In using STS. Want to send user name and password to STS for authentication from External website

Tags: asp.net, wif, claims-based-identity

I have configured thinktexture identity server which is connected with my database for authentication and returning the claims in response.

Now I am able to use STS in my website. Behavious of STS is, user is getting redirect to STS website login page for authentication and response is getting retun to my website after successfull login.

I want to implement a little bit different. I want to use Login page from my website itself instead of using this from STS so that stsyle and theming can be displayed as per my website.
Also want to implement many other password control features ie Password expiry warning, force change password etc can be implemented within the website.Please suggest the approach

Comment: Password expiry warning and change password should be implemented at the STS side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the WS-Trust endpoints that IdentityServer supports.

Comment: Can you please explain little more as I am not able to find anything that can solve my problem?

Comment: WS-Trust is a protocol for allowing a client app to use uid/pwd to get a token.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot RnD, we finally reach at conclusion that it cannot be achieved.

It will always redirect to identity server URL for authentication.